# Restored old iPhone 7 to use for music. But I'm stuck on the initial setup. How can I get past this?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, wifi

As the title mentions. I'm stuck. I factory reset my wife's old iPhone 7 and can't get it reactivated. It was one of the models with the faulty simcard slots therefore that no longer works.

When attempting to activate it shows the errors:

> The iPhone "iPhone" could not be activated because the activation information could not be obtained from the device. Disconnect your iPhone, make sure the SIM card is inserted correctly and if you use a SIM PIN, tap unlock to enter it and then reconnect your iPhone.

and

> Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting your iPhone to a PC or Mac to activate it, or try again in a couple of minutes.

Some things I've tried:

- Activating over WiFi, it fails and I get a message stating either, the activation server is currently down or that I need to update my ios before I can activate it.
- I tried doing it with my iPad, but that failed as well. Giving me the same messages as stated above.
- I tried updating via iTunes, but that gave me a message about the lack of sim card which I can do nothing about since the slot no longer works.
- Tried to factory reset multiple times.

I am so lost and have spent the last 6 and a half hours Googling and trying the things I've come across.. Which were essentially all the things I tried on my own.

So to summarize where I am at, I get to choose my language, country, WiFi network then it goes through the activating process. I never make it to the iCloud login portion.

Any ideas on what to try next? Thank you all for taking the time.

Comment: Please post the exact quoted error messages.

Comment: Message I get from iTunes when I try to update, "The iPhone "iPhone" could not be activated because the activation information could not be obtained from the device. Disconnect your iPhone, make sure the SIM card is inserted correctly and if you use a SIM PIN, tap unlock to enter it and then reconnect your iPhone."                                     Message from iPhone itself, "Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting your iPhone to a PC or Mac to activate it, or try again in a couple of minutes."